# SQL - Get value from next row based on specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
| ID | Ref | Type |              LogTime |
|----|-----|------|----------------------|
|  1 |  AA |    1 | 2019-05-03 18:30:01  |
|  2 |  BB |    1 | 2019-05-03 19:42:02  |
|  3 |  AA |    3 | 2019-05-04 12:30:03  |
|  4 |  BB |    3 | 2019-05-05 19:42:04  |
|  5 |  AA |    1 | 2019-05-06 20:55:05  |
```

I would like to list all rows with Type = 1 and to include the value of LogTime where Ref values are equal and Type =3

Something like this:

```
| ID | Ref | Type |              LogTime |        LogTime_Type3 |
|----|-----|------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 |  AA |    1 | 2019-05-03 18:30:01  | 2019-05-04 12:30:03  |
|  2 |  BB |    1 | 2019-05-03 19:42:02  | 2019-05-05 19:42:04  |
|  5 |  AA |    1 | 2019-05-06 20:55:05  | NULL                 |
```

I tried to use `LEAD(LogTime) Over..` but I were not able to specify the records with type=3

Can you please help.

Here is my [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63b33/13/0)

Comment: I don't understand why "5" doesn't have a value for ref 3.  It has a match.

Comment: because there is no record with type=3 and greater time than the corresponding record with type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `join`:

```
SELECT t.*, t3.LogTime as LogTime3
FROM Trans t LEFT JOIN
     Trans t3
     ON t3.ref = t.ref and t3.TYPE = '3'
WHERE t.TYPE = '1'
ORDER BY t.id;
```

One way to get the *next* time is to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT t.*, t3.LogTime as LogTime3
FROM Trans t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t3.*
      FROM Trans t3
      WHERE t3.ref = t.ref and
            t3.LogTime > t.LogTime and
            t3.TYPE = '3'
      ORDER BY t.LogTime ASC
     ) t3
WHERE t.TYPE = '1'
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Or, using window functions, a cumulative minimum seems the most appropriate:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MIN(CASE WHEN t.TYPE = '3' THEN t.LogTime END) OVER (PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY LogTime DESC) as LogTime3
      FROM Trans t 
     ) t
WHERE t.TYPE = '1'
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using subquery also we can achieve your expected output

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     O.ID,
     O.Ref,
     O.[Type],
     O.LogTime,
    (SELECT TOP 1 I.LogTime FROM LoginLogout I
     WHERE I.Ref = O.Ref
        AND I.[Type] = 3 
        AND I.LogTime > O.LogTime) AS LogTime_Type3 
FROM LoginLogout O
WHERE O.[Type] = 1
```